# Template functor cannot deduce reference type

Tags: c++, templates, reference, functor

I've got a functor f, which takes a function func and a parameter t of the same type as func. I cannot pass g to f because of compilation error (no matching function for call to `f(int&, void (&)(int&))` ). If g would take non-reference parameter g(int s), compilation finishes. Or if I manually specify template parameter `f<int&>(i, g)`, compilation also finishes.

```
template<typename T>
void f(T t, void (*func)(T)) {}

void g(int& s) {}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    int i = 7;

    f(i, g); // compilation error here

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get deduction to work?

Comment: Please take time to learn to enter code block (large and inline). Only after I edited your question does it become apparent that you are already aware of the explicit passing I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can invoke the function like this:

```
f<int&>(i, g);
```

But now i will be passed by reference too.

In general, I'd make the function a template type too:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void f(T t, F func) 
{ 
    func(t); //e.g
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you need either:

```
void f(T t, void (*func)(T&)) {}
```

or:

```
void g(int s) {}
```

but I prefer:

```
template<typename T, typename T2> 
void f(T t, T2 func) {}
```

as this will work with functions and functors.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that if in a template one of its function parameters is not a reference type before deduction starts, that parameter will never deduce to a reference type. So in the deduction on the left side, `T` yields `int`, but on the deduction on the right side, `T` yields `int&`. That's a mistmatch and the compiler complains.

The best is to make the function parameter the same type as the parameter type of the function pointer:

```
template<typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
void f(typename identity<T>::type t, void (*func)(T)) {}
```

By using `identity<T>::type`, you disable deduction on the left side. Once the `T` was determined at the right side, `T` is sustituted into the left side and yields the final parameter type.

One guy proposed to take the right side as a template parameter - this is a good thing since it can then accept function objects with `operator()` overloaded. But you then face the problem of having to know whether it wants a reference or not. To solve it, `boost` has `reference_wrapper` (by the way, `boost` also has the `identity` template above).

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void f(T t, F func) {}
```

Now, if you want to pass a reference and not a copy, you can do that like this

```
int i;
f(boost::ref(i), some_function);
```

`ref` returns a reference_wrapper object which is implicitly convertible to `T&`. So if you call `func(t)`, the `t` is converted to the target reference automagically. If you don't want to pass a reference, just pass `i` directly.

Comment: Hm, the `identity` version breaks with `const int i` too.

Comment: @gf can you please show an example? I'm not sure what you mean and where it breaks.

Comment: Sorry - when using `const int i` in the OPs example, `i` can't be passed to the resulting `f(int&,void(*)(int&))`.

Comment: @gf i think this is very much the intended behavior, though. Suppose `f` would accept it merely by its parameter. But that won't do any good, because we will still get an error when it calls `func(t)`. `f` does well with rejecting that upfront, unless i'm missing something :)

Comment: Euh, yes ... i am going to catch up on sleep now. Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
void f(T t, void (*func)(T)) {}
```

The key thing here is that you used `T` in both arguments.  That means the types have to match exactly.

```
void g(int& s) {}

int i = 7;
f(i, g);
```

In your code, you pass an `int` and a function taking an `int&` to `f()`.  Those are **different** types but your template for `f` expects two of the **same** type.  The easiest fix, as others have suggested, is to make the function a template as well.

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void f(T t, F func) 
{ 
    func(t);
}
```