# get const or non-const reference type from trait

Tags: c++, templates, reference, functor, traits

I am writing a functor F which takes function of type void (*func)(T) and func's argument arg.

```
template<typename T>
  void F(void (*func)(T), WhatTypeHere? arg)
{
  func(arg);
}
```

Then functor F calls func with arg. I would like F not to copy arg, just to pass it as reference. But then I cannot simply write "void F(void (*func)(T), T&)" because T could be a reference. So I am trying to write a trait, which allows to get proper reference type of T:

```
T -> T&
T& -> T&
const T -> const T&
const T& -> const T&
```

I come up with something like this:

```
template<typename T>
 struct type_op
{
 typedef T& valid_ref_type;
};

template<typename T>
 struct type_op<T&>
{
 typedef typename type_op<T>::valid_ref_type valid_ref_type;
};

template<typename T>
 struct type_op<const T>
{
 typedef const T& valid_ref_type;
};

template<typename T>
 struct type_op<const T&>
{
 typedef const T& valid_ref_type;
};


template<typename T>
  void F(void (*func)(T), typename type_op<T>::valid_ref_type arg)
{
  func(arg);
}
```

Which doesn't work for example for

```
void a(int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
F(&a, 7);
```

Giving error:
    invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from a temporary of type ‘int’  in passing argument 2 of ‘void F(void (*)(T), typename type_op::valid_ref_type) [with T = int]’

How to get this trait to work?

Comment: I think it's pretty similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539361/c-template-functor-cannot-deduce-reference-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct forwarding { typedef T const& type; };
template<class T>
struct forwarding<T&> { typedef T& type; };

template<typename T>
void F(void (*func)(T), typename forwarding<T>::type arg) {
  func(arg);
}

void a(int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
int main() {
  F(&a, 7);
}
```

Your mapping was close, you actually want T mapped to T const& too:

```
T        -> T const&
T&       -> T&
T const& -> T const&
```

Note that functions having a parameter type of T const have a signature of T!  The const is an implementation detail:

```
void f(int const);
typedef void F(int); // typedef of function type
F* p = &f; // no error! f's signature doesn't include const
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect solution. Also fixed call for reference argument: void a(int& x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to remove a reference:

```
template<typename T> struct remove_reference { typedef T type; };
template<typename T> struct remove_reference<T&> { typedef T type; };
```

Then add it again as follows:

```
remove_reference<T>::type&
```

Your function should be declared as follows:

```
template<typename T>
void F( void (*func)(T), const typename remove_reference<T>::type& arg )
{
  func(arg);
}
```

Comment: Same error with your trait: "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from a temporary of type ‘int’". Also passing const int& generates an error:
 
    const int& cri = 7;
    F(&a, cri);

"invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘const int’"

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the const. Works for me!

Comment: Will fail for `void f(int &n) { n = 0; } int main() { int n; F(f, n); }`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit vague in my mind, but I think that boost (maybe boost::bind) solves this by only providing `const T&` traits, and requiring the use of `ref(x)` to indicate a non-const reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use boost. But your answer is certainly correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`add_reference`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/add_reference.html) from Boost.TypeTraits to achieve the type-mapping you need.